# this attempt to set a cookie via set-cookie header was blocked

Tags: javascript, typescript, cookies

These is my cookie settings:

```
Max-Age=86400; Domain=https://domain.me; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 23 Aug 2022 18:18:55 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Strict
```

This is my domain:

```
https://domain.me
```

This is my api domain:

```
https://api.domain.me
```

But whenever i try to do a set-cookie i get this error:

```
this attempt to set a cookie via set-cookie header was blocked because its domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url.
```

How is this possible if the domain attribute is the same as the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `Https://` from the domain attribute in the cookie settings and it worked!